# how to retrieve mobile website html source code, android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve html source code from a mobile version website,

```
String url = "m.kitco.com";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

however, the source code that I could get was only the full site source code instead of mobile version. It seems like the web server automatically forward the link to full site.

How can I force it to retrieve the mobile website html source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add android user agent for example

```
  request.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
```